# Accordion inside a Flatlist React native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

I have an accordion inside a flatlist.

**Here is the code i have :**

```
const OptionList = (groupOption) => {
   return (
    <FlatList
      data={groupOption.options}
      keyExtractor={(result) => result.id.toString()}
       renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
         const clickedRadio = () => {
         const selectedOption = { [item.question]: { ...item } };
           setAnswers({ ...answers, ...selectedOption });
         };
         const status = isOptionSelected(item) ? true : false;

         return (
          <View key={index}>
            <Radio
              initialValue={status}
              label={item.description}
              onChange={() => clickedRadio()}
              color="error"
             />
          </View>
         );
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: 16, color:"#6B24AA" }}>
       {t("Choose an option/Scroll for more questions")}
      </Text>
  
      <FlatList
        data={questions}
        listKey={(item) => item.id.toString()}
        keyExtractor={(result) => result.id.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
          const data = [
          {
            title: item.description,
            content: (<><OptionList options= 
              {item?.question_options}></OptionList></>)
          }
         ];
       const status = isOptionSelected(item) ? true : false;
       return (
        <View style={styles.groupOptions} key={index}>
          <Accordion style={styles.accordion} 
           headerStyle= 
          {styles.headerStyle} contentStyle={styles.contentStyle} 
          dataArray={data} 
          icon={status ? <Icon name="circle" 
          family="Entypo" size={20} style={{marginLeft: -6, 
          color: "#6B24AA"}}/> 
          : 
           <Icon name="done" 
          family="MaterialIcons" size={20} 
          style={{marginLeft: -6}}/>} 
          expandedIcon={<Icon name="circle" 
          family="Entypo"/>} 
          opened={1}/>
        </View>
      );
    }}
  />
</View>
```

);

The accordion content its anther flatlist component. It shows this error every time i click the accordion.

**It shows this error :**

```
VirtualizedList: Encountered an error while measuring a list's offset from its containing VirtualizedList.
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js:1411:10 in _scrollRef.measureLayout$argument_2
```

How can i fix this error? Is it  the problem the other flatlist at the content of accordion

Comment: why are you using two `FlatList` ? make `OptionList` a simple component use `map` for looping. you don't have to make it so much complex.

Comment: Yeah actually, i dont know how i didnt think about that, long day :). If you want post it it as an answer so i can accept it . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace the `OptionList` component with the given below code.

**OptionList**

```
const OptionList = (groupOption) => {
return (
    groupOption.map((item,index) => {
        const clickedRadio = () => {
        const selectedOption = { [item.question]: { ...item } };
              setAnswers({ ...answers, ...selectedOption });
        };
        const status = isOptionSelected(item) ? true : false;
        return (
        <View key={index}>
         <Radio
           initialValue={status}
           label={item.description}
           onChange={clickedRadio}
           color="error"
          />
       </View>
        )
    })
 );
};
```

please check and let me know , cheers !

Answer (score 0):

You have the option to utilize the [react-native-accordion-list-view](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-accordion-list-view), which comes with built-in support for the flatList.

And here's an example on how to use the library:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import {View, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text, Platform, UIManager} from 'react-native';
import {AccordionList} from 'react-native-accordion-list-view';

const App = () => {
    const data = [
        {
            id: 0,
            title: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy',
            body: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy',
            body: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
        },
    ];
    useEffect(() => {
        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            if (UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental) {
                UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
            }
        }
    }, []);
    return (
        <SafeAreaView>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <AccordionList
                    data={data}
                    customTitle={item => <Text>{item.title}</Text>}
                    customBody={item => <Text>{item.body}</Text>}
                    animationDuration={400}
                    expandMultiple={true}
                />
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};

export default App;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        paddingVertical: '2%',
        paddingHorizontal: '3%',
        height: '100%',
        backgroundColor: '#e7e7e7',
    },
});
```

You can check the documentation for more information and documentation, Hope it helps you :D